# How do I mass-modify the bit rate of WAV files?

Tags: audio, wav, bitrate

I have about 200-250 WAV files that I need to work with in Unreal Editor for a game mod. The editor wouldn't accept WAV files with a bit rate higher than 768 kbps. Annoyingly, the WAV files are mostly in 1536 kbps.

I've tried using Audacity to convert them to a lower bit rate. It most certainly works, but it's quite tedious to do so for a large amount of files. I don't think Audacity can be used to batch process the files via command line, either.

Is there a faster or automated way to do this? The target format remains WAV, all I want to do is lower the bit rate from 1536 kbps to 768 kbps.

Comment: So you want to **resample** the audio files. Have a look at `sox`, and I guess even `ffmpeg` would work.